# change the core-dump location - abrtd configuration

Tags: linux, dump, kdump

I'm trying to change the Linux core-dump location to a different directory using the abrtd configuration

(normally it is going to the location core,but according to my research, if you enable abrtd, that will overwrite the default location.)

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/var/tmp/core-%e-%p-%t
```

abrtd.conf dump location looks like this

```
 DumpLocation = /data/kdump/abrt/FQDN    (this is a nfs mount)
```

Why my application core-dumps are not going to the  /data/kdump/abrt/FQDN rather /var/tmp location

Am i missing any configuration directive ?

Comment: Do you have SElinux enabled? Is `abrtd` service enabled and running?

Comment: Nope it is disabled.

Comment: Abrtd is running but selinux is disabled

Comment: The next thing is if `/data/kdump/abrt/FQDN` is writable for `abrtd`?

Comment: Yes, it has correct permissions.